Does AWS IAM Passrole always require Trust Relationship to work?
Is Trust Relationship required for both Passrole and AssumeRole to work?
There are AWS CLI commands that take in the --role-arn parameter. If --role-arn is specified, the AWS service would assume this role to perform operations.
If I have a user account User1 with user_role who executes the command cloudformation create ... --role-arn admin_role:

Does User1 require Passrole permission to specify the --role-arn parameter to pass admin_role to CloudFormation?
And is a trust relationship required for CloudFormation to assume admin_role?

In a hypothetical situation, if admin_role is not passed (Passrole) to CloudFormation and CloudFormation initiates the AssumeRole to admin_role itself, does this also require a trust relationship?
References

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-the-passrole-permission-with-iam-roles

